# Google crawling errors for old links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, blogger, google-search-console

Google Webmasters Tools is showing some server and crawling errors for my old links blog on Blogger. Years ago I bought a domain name and did that typical 301 redirect that eliminates the blogspot from the url name. Then months later I bought a hosting and transferred all the files to it. Following, I delete the site that was hosted on Blogger, after doing all the redirects and waiting for Google to index the new links, course.

But Google keeps crawling my old Blogger links and showing as Soft 404 Error. Example: "blogname.com/2014/04/oldlinkpost.html", "blogname.com/search/label/oldtagpost".

NOTE: I don't work with PHP. Static HTML only.

I'm thinking of fixing this through htaccess (maybe a 301 redirect).

What I'd like to do is: redirect any url that contains date and the words "search/label" to my homepage, since I don't use dates or these characters (search and label) in my current links.

I have these lines in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^search/label/(.*)$ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{1,2})_([0-9]{1,2})_archive$ http://example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work anymore. Any old link now falls on page 404.

I tried this also:

```
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.+?)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

But nothing done either.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try moving these rules to the top of your .htaccess file (just after the first `RewriteEngine On` statement). This helped me when I faced a similar issue

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Prayag Verma. I tried but it also did'nt work. For now, the errors stopped appearing. But by parsing the server log files, I found a gzip with logs that the server stores in cPanel with references to those old links. Can bots read server log files? That confused me! Anyway, thank you for the answer.